# Data not updated on Production DB

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a weird situation on my project. I have 2 entities: children and users. Users create children, so on children, I have a reference to their owners and on users I have a list of the children they have created.

When I add a new child to firebase, the user owner of that child has his list of children updated to add that new child.

The thing is: on the staging environment everything works as it should be. But on the production environment, the child is added to the children, but not to the list of children on users.

Both databases have the same rules.

I've got to this project when it was already partially developed, so I can't even find where specifically the user should be updated. It seems to me that when you update a child, the users entity is automagically updated (using breakpoints I could verify it actually happens on the same step). I'm kind of new to Firebase so I am really lost here.

Can anyone try to help me?

Here are the database rules:

```
{"rules": {
"children": {
  "$uid": {
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first_name'])",
    "date_of_birth": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^(19|20)\\d\\d-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)"
    },
    "first_name": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"
    },
    "users": {
      "$key2": {
        ".validate": "root.child('users').child($key2).val() != null && newData.isString() && newData.val() == 'parent'"
      },
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()"
    },
    "$other": {
      ".validate": "false"
    },
    ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
    ".write": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() == 'parent' || newData.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() == 'parent'"
  }
},
"users": {
  ".indexOn": [
    "email"
  ],
  "$uid": {
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()",
    "email": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() == auth.token.email"
    },
    "first_name": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    },
    "is_subscribed": {
      ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
    },
    "children": {
      "$key5": {
        ".validate": "root.child('children').child($key5).val() != null && newData.isString() && newData.val() == 'parent'"
      },
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()"
    },
    "$other": {
      ".validate": "false"
    },
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
  }
}
```

}
}

and the code that adds children to it.

```
var entityDatabase: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child(“children”).child(did)
entityDatabase.keepSynced(true)

var firstName: String?
var users: [String: String] = [:]



var params: [String: Any] {

    var strings: [String: String] = [:]

    strings["first_name"] = firstName

    let keysToRemove = strings.keys.filter { strings[$0] == "" }

    for key in keysToRemove {
        strings.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }

    var dict: [String: Any] = strings
    dict["users"] = users

    return dict
}

guard let user = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return
    }

    guard firstName?.isEmpty == false else {
        return
    }

    users[user.uid] = "parent"

    entityDatabase.updateChildValues(params) { [weak self] (error, _) in
        self?.observe()

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        switch self?.updatedImage {
        case let image?:
            self?.save(image: image, completion: completion)
        case nil:
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a rules issue (a node name being different) or a app reference issue (pointing to the wrong node). However, no way to tell without seeing a code snippet and Firebase structure and maybe even the rules. If you update your question with that data (as TEXT please, NO images) we may be able to help. Also, it's not clear what *you update a child, the users entity is automagically updated* means - the only structures are key: value pairs known as parent and child nodes and they only update when you add, change or remove data.

Comment: I checked the rules and they are the same on both environments. Anyway, I added the relevante parte of rules and code to my question. I would appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: Well, right off the bat, any writes done with this code will be written ONLY to the /children node due to *Database.database().reference().child(“children”).child(did)* (i.e. rootRef/children/did - not sure what *did* is) so nothing would be written to a rootRef/users node.

Comment: That's what makes sense to me... but what puzzles me is that on the updateChildValues step both children and users references are updated on the staging environment.

Comment: did was a typo. It's actually uid.

Comment: That code isn't going to update anything in the users node - there must be more code elsewhere that references the fbRef.child("users") node. Also, there's some code that's unused, like *users[user.uid] = "parent"* that may be a clue as you can 'back up' a node by examining the ref.parent node. There may be a Firebase Cloud Function in play here as well that's triggered when the children node is updated.

Comment: Actually, I found out there is a function that updates the "users" node when a child is created. But still, it is not working properly on the production environment.... I've seen the source code and it is the same as on the staging one...

Comment: By *function* you mean there's a function in your app that writes data to both nodes. That function is not a specific Firebase function but is a function coded in the App that writes data to both locations. That's probably where the issue is and/or references that function uses are incorrect. You should update your question to include that function code, any parameters passed in and what Firebase references it uses.

Comment: By "function" I meant function, in Firebase. It suddenly stopped being called by Firebase. I still don't why, but the problem was solved by re-deploying the functions to Firebase.